# Why heroku fails to bind to $PORT when I use webpack.definePlugin with parsed dotenv

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, dotenv

I am trying to deploy a node.js app to heroku which is bundled with webpack. Due to heroku logs I face with the following error:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

App does not use a fixed port to listen on.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  log(`App is running:  http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`, 'info');
});
```

I have also tried to use '0.0.0.0':

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0' () => {
  log(`App is running:  http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`, 'info');
});
```

I noticed that if I use webpack.definePlugin with parsed dotenv I face with this issue, but if I don't use it all is fine.

I have the following .env file that I use for webpack.definePlugin:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const paths = require('./paths');

const defaultVars = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
};

const stringifyEnv = (obj) => ({
  'process.env': Object.keys(obj).reduce((env, key) => {
    env[key] = JSON.stringify(obj[key]);
    return env;
  }, {})
});

module.exports = () => {
  if (fs.existsSync(paths.dotenv)) {
    const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
    const env = { ...dotenv.parsed, ...defaultVars };
    return stringifyEnv(env);
  }

  return stringifyEnv(defaultVars);
};
```

Tried to list dotenv in devDependencies.

Could you please tell what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it working by passing a port explicitly.

Procfile

```
web: node build/server/server.js --port $PORT
```

server.js

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
...
app.listen(argv.port || process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  log(`App is running:  http://localhost:${argv.port || process.env.PORT || 3000}`, 'info');
});
```

But it still does not answer the question above.